# Tracking repeating items in Org-Mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm wondering if there's a way of tracking daily repeating tasks in org-mode. For example lets say I have a list of things to do every day -

```
* TODO Task 1
* TODO Task 2
* TODO Task 3
```

Is there a way to have the tasks under a new daily date heading automatically, so it might become -

```
* TASKS
** April 17 [/]
*** TODO Task 1
*** TODO Task 2
*** TODO Task 3
** April 18 [/]
*** TODO Task 1
*** TODO Task 2
*** TODO Task 3

...ETC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use org-mode's [agenda mode](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Agenda-Views) to organize your tasks, which I recommend, you can add `+1d` to your task's timestamp to make it recur daily. The example given in the [Dates and Times](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Dates-and-Times) section of the manual is `Pick up Sam at school <2007-05-16 Wed 12:30 +1w>`.

Comment: Thanks I tried the example and that's really useful but is there any way to group it into days like my example instead of tasks so I can look back and check how many tasks where completed on any given day?

Comment: It looks like this is the best way to go in org-mode